# The execution phase run for 2 minutes during which time customers will arrive randomly between 2 - 6 seconds and be placed into a queue

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I managed to get the customers showing up at random times, the only problem I have now is wrapping the whole thing in a 2-minute timer without conflicting with the customer arrivals.

```
static Timer timer = new Timer();

static class Task extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int delay = (new Random().nextInt(5)+2) * 1000;
        timer.schedule(new Task(), delay);
        System.out.println("Hi " + delay);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Task().run();
}
```

This is what I have that works so far. I've tried wrapping it in another `TimerTask`, and using `System.nanoTime()` and a while loop. They both just end up conflicting with the customer arrivals. I usually like to figure things out on my own, but I've been working on this one part for hours and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use a sleep with a `do-while` loop like:

```
long durationMillis = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + durationMillis;
do {
  int delaySec = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2, 7);
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(delaySec);
  System.out.println("Hi " + delaySec);
} while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);
```

Change `delaySec` semantics if you don't need to wait for whole seconds or 6 second wait is not inclusive.